# $AnimatedSprite2D.play will not play my idle anim at game start even when adding into _ready function. Only plays walk until I enter detection

Tags: 2d, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

This is within GOdot. I have a slime enemy that has a detection shape which is on a differnt layer to my other assets. My player character is on both layers.

Below is my slime script. Which works great but there is one problem with the animations.I want the "slime_idle" to play at game start and when my player exits enemy detection. Exiting works as expected, but at game start my "walk" animation is played outside of detection. I tried adding the "slime_idle" to _ready but still plays "walk".

Any help and explination would be massively appreciated.

```
extends CharacterBody2D


var speed = 50
var player_chase = false
var player = null

func _physics_process(delta):
    if player_chase:
        position += (player.position - position).normalized() * speed * delta
        move_and_collide(Vector2(0,0)) 
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("walk")
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.play("slime_idle")
    
func _on_detection_area_body_entered(body):
    player = body
    player_chase = true



func _on_detection_area_body_exited(body):
    player = null
    player_chase = false
    player_chase = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that you should check.

1. On the AnimatedSprite2D, you have the idle animation assigned to the Animation variable.
2. Your idle animation has "Autoplay on Load" enabled, and not one of your other animations such as walk.